# Fail2ban regex doesn't match my log

Tags: wordpress, regex, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks

I'm trying to create a failregex in Fail2ban to find these lines ( and IP addresses ), but I can't write it.

My log lines looks like these:

> [Thu Sep 22 10:28:32.215159 2016] [:error] [pid 1616] [client
>   83.143.240.13:54895] FastCGI: server "/var/www/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-104.236.209.45-80-blogginger.com" stderr:
>   PHP message: WP login failed for username: admin, referer:
>   http://blogginger.com/wp-login.php
>
> [Thu Sep 22 04:38:01.588441 2016] [:error] [pid 24937] [client
>   49.151.91.8:58121] FastCGI: server "/var/www/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-104.236.209.45-80-blogginger.com" stderr:
>   PHP message: WP login failed for username: admin, referer:
>   http://blogginger.com/wp-login.php

And this is my failregex line in attack.conf:

```
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] WP login failed.*
```

But it doesn't work. There is not any match.

What is the correct failregex line for find these log lines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
failregex = \[client <HOST>:\d+\] .* WP login failed
```

You can use the `fail2ban-regex` utility to test regexes against example input files. That's a lot quicker and easier than trying to do this with the live logs.

Comment: I upgraded the server, and log has been changed:
[Mon Dec 03 07:03:18.364323 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 12662] [client 103.200.39.34:7379] WP login failed for username: admin, referer: https://blogginger.com/login

The correct regex now is this below:
\[client <HOST>:\d+\] .*WP login failed.*

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] .*WP login failed.*
```